# Connections to an Access database are stalling (looping?) on IIS

Tags: loops, ms-access, iis, connection

I have a pc with windows server 2008 (but it also happens with Windows Server 2003) and IIS, with different installed sites, which normally function properly. 
Sometimes (2-3 times a day) it happens that the mdb connection of the server stalling, in the sense that all the sites that read mdb database come into a kind of loop, since the browser returns the classic timeout error. 
Not depend on the database or from the site, but occurs on all sites on the server. In general, they are sites in asp with classic ADODB connection. The web access continues to operate, it's just the mdb connection that goes into loop. 
It’s sufficient to restart the service of web publishing or restart IIS, to run again the connection, but I want to prevent the problem, not solve it every time someone report it. 
May depend on what? Some of the sites that does something that is blocking the mdb connection on entire server? A hacker attack of some kind? How can I monitor any abnormal behavior of the sites or external attacks?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using an Access database file (.mdb or .accdb) as a back-end database for a web application.

[Microsoft strongly recommends against it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653753.aspx#access_database); it is simply the wrong approach for a number of reasons.

Comment: The users of my server are using a mdb database, not me. I can not tell everyone to change database ... 
I am still waiting some concrete advice, thank you.